# Как узнать который час Phyton

Tags: python, datetime

Как мне найти который час? Именно час, без минут, желательно в 24 формате.

Я пытался воспользоваться библиотекой datetime, но получилось достать только время в формате `Час:минуты:секунды`, а мне же нужно только Час.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
moment = now.time()
print(moment)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужно к существующему коду добавить всего лишь несколько букв:

```
print(moment.hour)
```

*PS. Учитесь читать документацию, там всё это есть.*

Answer (score 4):

```
import time

dt  = time.strftime("%H")
print(dt)
23
```

Comment: Это не на библиотеке datetime.